# Где хранить тесты в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Где правильно хранить тесты в React, и какие подходы существуют?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошей практикой считается хранить тесты в папке компонента, с названием в следующим формате:

```
Component.test.js
```

или

```
Component.specs.js
```

Если к конкретному тесту/тестам сложно применить понятие "описывающий", то тогда предпочтительно использовать универсальный вариант `test` (вместо `specs`).